# Automated tests in jenkins object instantiation errors Using Laravel phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, object, jenkins

I am running automated tests in jenkins on an aws linux server using nginx and php7.3. When the tests are run I am getting the following errors

```
    1) Tests\Feature\admin\EventManagementTest::test_admin_can_edit_event_and_view_in_event_list
Error: Call to a member function path() on null

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/answers-integration/tests/Feature/admin/EventManagementTest.php:134

2) Tests\Feature\admin\EventManagementTest::test_admin_can_soft_delete_event_and_does_not_appear_on_event_list
Error: Call to a member function path() on null

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/answers-integration/tests/Feature/admin/EventManagementTest.php:190
```

Function path() is located in my Event model

On my local environment, everything works fine. Every test passes

Objects are not being instantiated and I have no ideas as to why

The following code is where it's failing to instantiate the object with an eloquent query

```
 $event = Event::with('event_categories', 'event_topics')->find(1);
```

This happens to the majority of my tests. Below is the full test code

```
namespace Tests\Feature\admin;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Tests\TestCase;
use \App\Event;

class EventManagementTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker, DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->seed();
    }


    public function test_admin_can_create_event_and_view_in_event_list()
    {
        //login as admin
        $admin = $this->signInAsAdmin();

        $attributes = [
            'event_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'event_description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
            'event_start_date_time' => $this->faker->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'event_end_date_time' => $this->faker->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'organisation_name' => $this->faker->company,
            'location' => $this->faker->address,
            'contact_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'contact_phone' => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
            'contact_email' => $this->faker->email,
            'contact_link' => $this->faker->url,
            'venue' => $this->faker->address,
            'event_categories' => [1,2],
            'event_topics' => [2,3]
        ];

        //create new event
        $this->post('/admin/events', $attributes);

        //retrieve event from database
        $event = Event::with('event_categories', 'event_topics')->find(1);

        //ensure the event data is in the database
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('events', ['event_name' => $attributes['event_name'], 'event_description' => $attributes['event_description']]);

        //ensure the data is in the pivot tables for categories
        foreach ($event->event_categories AS $event_category){
            $this->assertDatabaseHas('content_category_event', [
                'event_id' => $event_category->pivot->event_id,
                'content_category_id' => $event_category->pivot->content_category_id
            ]);
        }

        //ensure the data is in the pivot tables for tags
        foreach ($event->event_topics AS $event_topics){
            $this->assertDatabaseHas('content_tag_event', [
                'event_id' => $event_topics->pivot->event_id,
                'content_tag_id' => $event_topics->pivot->content_tag_id
            ]);
        }

        //make sure the title appears on the group list
        $this->get('/admin/events')->assertSee($attributes['event_name']);
    }

    public function test_admin_can_edit_event_and_view_in_event_list()
    {
        //login as admin
        $admin = $this->signInAsAdmin();

        $attributes = [
            'event_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'event_description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
            'event_start_date_time' => $this->faker->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'event_end_date_time' => $this->faker->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'organisation_name' => $this->faker->company,
            'location' => $this->faker->address,
            'contact_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'contact_phone' => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
            'contact_email' => $this->faker->email,
            'contact_link' => $this->faker->url,
            'venue' => $this->faker->address,
            'event_categories' => [1,2],
            'event_topics' => [2,3]
        ];

        //create new event
        $this->post('/admin/events', $attributes);

        //retrieve event from database
        $event = Event::with('event_categories', 'event_topics')->find(1);

        $attributes_edit = [
            'event_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'event_description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
            'event_start_date_time' => $this->faker->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'event_end_date_time' => $this->faker->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'organisation_name' => $this->faker->company,
            'location' => $this->faker->address,
            'contact_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'contact_phone' => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
            'contact_email' => $this->faker->email,
            'contact_link' => $this->faker->url,
            'venue' => $this->faker->address,
            'event_categories' => [3,2],
            'event_topics' => [2,1]
        ];

        //update event
        $this->put($event->path(), $attributes_edit);

        //retrieve event from database
        $event = Event::with('event_categories', 'event_topics')->find(1);

        //ensure the event data is in the database
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('events', [
            'event_name' => $attributes_edit['event_name'],
            'location' => $attributes_edit['location']
        ]);

        //ensure the data is in the pivot tables for categories
        foreach ($event->event_categories AS $event_category){
            $this->assertDatabaseHas('content_category_event', [
                'event_id' => $event_category->pivot->event_id,
                'content_category_id' => $event_category->pivot->content_category_id
            ]);
        }

        //ensure the data is in the pivot tables for tags
        foreach ($event->event_topics AS $event_topics){
            $this->assertDatabaseHas('content_tag_event', [
                'event_id' => $event_topics->pivot->event_id,
                'content_tag_id' => $event_topics->pivot->content_tag_id
            ]);
        }

        //make sure the title appears on the group list
        $this->get('/admin/events')->assertSee($attributes_edit['event_name']);
    }

    public function test_admin_can_soft_delete_event_and_does_not_appear_on_event_list()
    {
        //login as admin
        $admin = $this->signInAsAdmin();

        $attributes = [
            'event_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'event_description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
            'event_start_date_time' => $this->faker->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'event_end_date_time' => $this->faker->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'organisation_name' => $this->faker->company,
            'location' => $this->faker->address,
            'contact_name' => $this->faker->name,
            'contact_phone' => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
            'contact_email' => $this->faker->email,
            'contact_link' => $this->faker->url,
            'venue' => $this->faker->address,
            'event_categories' => [1,2],
            'event_topics' => [2,3]
        ];

        //create new event
        $this->post('/admin/events', $attributes);
        $event = Event::with('event_categories', 'event_topics')->find(1);

        $this->delete($event->path());

        //check the record has been soft deleted
        $this->assertSoftDeleted('events', ['event_name' => $attributes['event_name']]);

        //make sure the event name does not appear in event list
        $this->get('/admin/users')->assertDontSee($attributes['event_name']);

    }
```

}

**EDIT**

A further update doing a dd($this->post('/admin/events', $attributes)) I get the following error:

```
exception: Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException^ {#3806
      #message: "CSRF token mismatch."
      #code: 0
      #file: "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php"
      #line: 83
      trace: {
```

How can a token be passed during a test?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards
Danny

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem from the following post

[TokenMismatchException in Laravel's auth form](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/53-tokenmismatchexception-in-laravels-auth-form)